# Mitigation techniques for Insecure direct object reference

Tags: owasp

what are the mitigation techniques for preventing horizontal privilege escalation through insecure direct object reference other than securing the session ? In other words, how do we achieve access controls on horizontal level, I mean the functionality, data, etc is accessible to everyone on the same level, if we are breaching privilege I feel the only possible way other than hijacking session is through Insecure direct object reference or is there any other way that I'm not aware of ?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from horizontally or vertically, IDOR occurs when the authorization check has forgotten to reach an object in the system. It is critical if the reached object is sensitive like displaying an invoice belongs to users in the system.

So, I advise using `randomly generated IDs or UUIDs` to avoid IDOR in total. The attacker has to find valid random ID values that belong to another user.

Or if this sounds hard to apply cus it's possible. Even if you use auto-incremented object IDs you can apply a **hash function with salt and put in a hash map like key-value pair. Then you’ll store the key-value map in the Session.**

Instead of exposing auto-increment IDs to the user, you can use hash values of corresponding IDs. When you get the value back from the user, you can find an actual ID value by looking up the key-value map in the Session. So that means, even if the attacker spoof the generated value it’s not going to exist on the map. Basically that means IDOR is not going to exploitable anymore.

To read all about IDOR and mitigation here is a post I wrote about it considering every possible aspect: https://medium.com/@aysebilgegunduz/everything-you-need-to-know-about-idor-insecure-direct-object-references-375f83e03a87

Answer (score 1):

may be use below link to prevent the Insecure Direct Object Reference:  http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/AccessReferenceMap.html